# How to decode/encode "\uNNNN"

Tags: python

I look for Python3 lib to encode-decode such JS coding, example from JS text:

```
// return '\u53EF\u80FD\u539F\u56E0\uFF1A' + kn;
```

I want to convert such coded text (in a JS file) to str, then encode str again.
Is such library existing?

Comment: Unicode escape sequences are handled by Python: `'\u53EF\u80FD\u539F\u56E0\uFF1A' == '可能原因：'`

Comment: I need to encode-decode such txt into string. No matter what python does. This txt is not Py code. It is 3rd party text.

Comment: You are looking for "unicode-escape"-encoding. First convert your text to a byte-sequence and then decode it using "unicode-escape"-encoding: `'\u53EF\u80FD\u539F\u56E0\uFF1A'.encode("ascii").decode("unicode-escape")`

Comment: It is the answer, can you post it.

Comment: @jojonas That code doesn't work for Python 3. You can't encode that unicode literal to ascii.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I tested it like this `r'\u53EF\u80FD\u539F\u56E0\uFF1A'.encode("ascii").decode("unicode-escape")`. Note the `r` at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From comments:
it is "unicode-escape"-encoding. First convert your text to a byte-sequence and then decode it using "unicode-escape"-encoding: `'\u53EF\u80FD\u539F\u56E0\uFF1A'.encode("ascii").decode("unicode-escape")`.